# Best Bar Code Scanner for both Web Form/ Win Form input

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, code39

I have an application that prints eTickets. Originally I used the cool 2-D bar code because it allowed me to use the GUID as the code. However scanners that can scan 2-D bar codes are way too expensive. So now I just use any of the codes that the Telerik Reporting too offers, like code39
http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/barcodes/demo.aspx

---

I want to allow people to scan the bar code with a scanner connected to the host computer via USB. The scanned code should automatically appears on the textbox of either the Web Form or win Form.

**What USB Hand-held scanners do you recommend in the sub-$100 range?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got the "Adesso NuScan 1000U Bar Code Reader"

If you use it on a Web Form, it works like this:
You click in the textbox, when developing the page you may want to use a javascript focus to make sure that the textbox is pre-selected.

Then you scan the bar code.

The scanner will put the bar code directly into the textbox and hit the return key.

If you are using .net web forms I would recommend putting your form in a asp:panel and in the panal properties set the default button to the button id. This way the correct button will be hit on return.

Here's the details of my results: [Bar Code Scanning for eTicketing software](http://support.simpletick.com/KB/a24/what-kind-of-bar-code-scanner-can-i-use.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the USB scanners go, this isn't the site for that kind of question. However, you may want to look on [Google Shopping.](http://www.google.com/products?hl=de&source=hp&q=usb%20barcode%20scanner&lr=&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wf)

Many of the barcode scanners turn the image into a numerical sequence based on the width of the bars. Given that they do that I've seen a few of these scanners act as a HID [keyboard/mouse input device]. I would instruct the user to put the cursor in a text box and scan, or type the bar code number in manually. After there is a text change, send a AJAX request or postback to handle the logic from there.

Comment: I agree.  Try looking for wand/pen scanners if you'll be scanning low volume and want super-cheap.

Answer (score 1):

you could go through the trouble of implementing a webcam as a barcode scanner.  Google returns lots of results.  Here's one from sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/

This has the benefit of being really cheap and available to many people, but it doesn't work as awesomely as does a real scanner.